# pointer to two-Dimension array access conflict

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int arr_2D[3][3]={ {1,2,3},
                      {11,22,33},
                      {111,222,333} };
    int (*ptr)[3]=arr_2D;
    
    printf("ptr=0x%0X\n",ptr+1); // ptr=0x60FEE4
    
    printf("*(ptr)=0x%0X\n",*(ptr+1)); //*(ptr+1)=0x60FEE4
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to access the location stored in (ptr+1) by using the dereference operator *
How come the output of ptr+1 equals to the output of *(ptr+1) ?  `

Comment: A pointer pointing at the array contains the same address as the array itself, as well as the address of the first item in the array. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Their value is the same, their type isn't. `ptr+1` is a pointer to an array (of 3 ints); `*(ptr + 1)` is a pointer to an int. Imagine you point your finger at me... and somebody else points her finger at my nose. Are you both pointing to the same "thing"?

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it in more simple words:

1. `int (*ptr)[3]=arr_2D;` defines `ptr` as pointer to **array** of three `int` elements.
2. `(ptr + 1)` is giving a **pointer to array** of three `int` elements
3. Dereferencing a pointer to array `*(ptr + 1)` is giving an **array** of three `int` elements.
4. When `array` is used in an expression (like function parameter) it decays to **pointer** to its first element.
5. As `(ptr + 1)` and decayed `*(ptr + 1)` reference the same location in memory, the `printf` will print the same value. The only difference is the **type** of the pointer.

Comment: Now I get it .. Thanks^^

Answer (score 0):

For starters to output pointers you need to use conversion specifier `p` instead of `X`

```
printf("ptr=%p\n",( void * )( ptr+1) ); // ptr=0x60FEE4

printf("*(ptr)=%p\n", ( void * )*(ptr+1)); //*(ptr+1)=0x60FEE4
```

The conversuib specifier `X` is designed to output objects of the type `unsigned int`.

Using a wrong conversion specifier invokes undefined behavior.

The expression `*( ptr + 1 )` has type `int[3]` due to the declaration of the pointer `ptr`

```
int (*ptr)[3]=arr_2D;
```

that is equivalent to

```
int (*ptr)[3] = &arr_2D[0];
```

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first element.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression
> with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the
> array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register
> storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So the expression `*( ptr + 1 )` having the array type `int[3]` and is used as an argument expression is implicitly converted to the pointer type `int *` to its first element.

Though the types of the expressions `ptr + 1` and `*( ptr + 1 )` used as arguments on the calls of printf are different (the first one has the type `int ( * )[3]` and the second one after the implicit conversion has the type `int *`) nevertheless they have equal values - the address of the extent of memory occupied by the second "row" of the array `arr_2D`.

Thus you have the following chains of implicit conversions of expressions with array types

```
int[3][3] (arr_2D)    -> int ( * )[3] (ptr)
int[3] (*( ptr + 1) ) -> int *
```

Comment: I can't get it though .. (ptr+1) outputs a location and it is supposed to get the value stored in it when using the * operator but it doesn't occur in the code !

Comment: @HossamAhmed The expression ptr + 1 points to the second row of the array arr_2D that has the type int[3]. So dereferencing the pointer expression *( ptr + 1 ) you will get the whole one-dimensional array of the type int[3].

Comment: @HossamAhmed To get the first element of the type int of the array you need to dereference the result expression  one more like **( ptr + 1 ). It is similar to using one dimensional arrays as for example int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; To get the first element of the array you can write printf( "%d\n", *a ); On the other hand, you have a pointer to a whole array in your original example.  So the first dereferencing will give you only one-dimensional array as in the example above. And to get its first element you need to dereference it one more.

Comment: Thanks alot .. I get it now ^^